# SDK Version Issue Failed while Uploading Build

Tags: swift, xcode

WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.but im using xcode 10.1 and sdk version 10.1 as shown in screen shot.

Sdk Version Description .1
DeploymentTargey.2

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpQBc.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bznqg.png

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is very precise and tells you what you need to do: Update your app to use the iOS 12.1 SDK. This unrelated to the deployment target of iOS 11.1 that you're showing us.

Comment: can u check new added image of terminal for sdk verion im using sdk verion 12.1